# reverse array of objects gives same output 2

Tags: javascript

I'm reversing only ab yet I'm getting the output as both ab and bb reversed..How do I get over that?

```js
var ab = [{
  c: 1,
  b: 3
}, {
  a: 1
}]
var bb = new Object(ab)
ab.reverse()
console.log(ab)
console.log(bb)
```

Comment: try reading about copying objects in javascript, especially about deep copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` for cloning an object:

```js
var ab = [{c:1, b:3},{a:1}]
var bb = Object.assign([], ab)
ab.reverse()
console.log(ab)
console.log(bb)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reverse` mutates the source array. I believe that this answers your issue itself: you're pointing to the same array which has been mutated by `Array#reverse`!

`Array#slice`/`Array#from`/array spread do the trick to clone the array:

```js
var ab = [{
  c: 1,
  b: 3
}, {
  a: 1
}]

const bb = ab.slice(0)
const cc = Array.from(ab)
const dd = [...ab]

ab.reverse()

console.log(ab)
console.log(bb)
console.log(cc)
console.log(dd)
```

Comment: How do I get over that...I need 2 copies 1 reversed and another not

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another array before reversing. `new Object(obj)` just returns `obj`. You could use `slice` instead.

```js
var ab = [{c:1, b:3},{a:1}]
var bb= new Object(ab)

console.log(ab === bb);

// create another array
var cb = ab.slice(0);

console.log(ab === cb);
cb.reverse();
console.log(ab);
console.log(cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(new Object(ab)).slice(0);` so that when a new object it created it is not the reference of `ab` but a new isolate object:

```js
var ab = [{c:1, b:3},{a:1}]
var bb= (new Object(ab)).slice(0);
ab.reverse()
console.log(ab)
console.log(bb)
```

You can also use **spread operator** to clone object in a new object:

```js
var ab = [{c:1, b:3},{a:1}]
var bb= [...ab];
ab.reverse()
console.log(ab)
console.log(bb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse is a destructive function. It also changes the original array. You have to use slice function.

```
var ab = [{c:1, b:3},{a:1}]
var bb= ab.slice()
ab.reverse()
console.log(ab)
console.log(bb)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `Array.prototype.concat` to create a new instance in memory and then execute the function `reverse`.

> #### [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
>
> The **`concat()`** method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.
>
> #### Return value
>
> A new `Array` instance.

```js
var ab = [{c: 1,b: 3}, {a: 1}],
    bb = [].concat(ab).reverse();

console.log(ab);
console.log(bb);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```